# Bootstrap 3 - Trying to match animate scrolltop to speed of collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and have several Panels within a panel-group and using collapse on each of the panels.  Expand/collapse works great.

I also have jquery(animate to scrolltop) to scroll the window to top of the collapsed panel upon hide.bs.collapse event. This works great too.

What I am trying to do, is match the animate scrolltop to the speed of the bootstrap collapse, so that the window scrolls up along with collapse.  Currently, depending on the speed of the animate, the window scroll ahead of collapse or lags behind it.

Not sure if what I am asking is possible. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post the code, so I kept question simple. If I could determine the speed of collapse, I should be able to use same value for animate. Unless both cannot be done concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some debugging, I determined that the actual rate at which the collapse occurs varies upon how large the expanded panel was.  This may or not be accurate statement, but analysis of timings showed that.

So I would say it's not possible to get the scroll to match each panel collapse exactly(if different sizes), but most of my panels are fairly close in size so I match that average rate and it works as I like.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling while animating is not good. The browser will be painting a large section of the page while attempting to scroll which is just not going to look good for anybody who is not on a very strong machine (ie. all mobile devices and most laptops).

Buuuuut, that doesn't answer your question. You're best bet is to collapse the panel and then immediately start 'polling' using `requestAnimationFrame`. For each callback, you can perform the calculations you need to determine how much the scroll position should change and set the scroll position manually. This is also your best defense against any performance issues. Here's some pseudocode:

```
somePanel.collapse();

let newPosition = 0;
function calculatePosition() {
  // calculate the new scroll position
  newPostion = doSomeFancyMathHere();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(setScroll);
}
function setScroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, newPostion);
  if (window.scrollTop > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(calculatePosition);
  }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(calculatePosition);'
```

**NOTE:** We are doing the calculations and the scrolling in separate animation frames because your fancy math calculations are going to cause a paint to happen. After performing the calculations, you will want to wait until the next animation frame to scroll.

If your calculations are correct, then any easing which takes place in the panel collapsing should be mimicked by the scrolling.